# Css/js/font files not loading in the Admin area - except two

Tags: magento2, admin, filesystem

I'm just starting with **Magento 2.0** and after realizing I won't be able to use it on my web server (**MySQL 5.5**) I decided to install it within my local XAMPP environment on Win 10.

Installation went good but when I access the admin area, only two files (`styles.css` and `require-config.js`) load fine. Rest is **404**. Check screenshot below

[image: Inspect/Network tab]

I'm running it at localhost:9000.
Styles.css. which loads fine, has a path http://localhost:9000/pub/static/version1509531285/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/css/styles.css

Ext-all.css, which doesn't load, had path http://localhost:9000/pub/static/version1509531285/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/extjs/resources/css/ext-all.css

Any ideas?

Comment: do you have run the static content deploy command?

Comment: Run static content deploy command then see static directory inside pub. if files are generated then check files/directories permissions.

Comment: OK, didn't know I need to do that, so I did. It's even worse now tho, all resources are 404 across the board, both frontend and backend. Files are created and pub/static fully populated but it doesn't load them. System tries to load from path pub/static/version1509641583/adminhtml (...) tho which is non existent (the version folder does not exist inside pub/static tho I assume this is a cache related rewrite or something?)

Comment: OK, it's all good now, decided to reinstall Magento from scratch and run static deploy again just after. Must have done something previously trying to address the problem 'manually' or something, This time it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Ok, it's back to 'broken' again and this time redeploying static files does not help at all. All of a sudden the frontend started to generate 404s on all static files and now, after running redeploy command, backend is throwing 404s as well. I'm not even sure what info to feed you so you are able to advice